# Linear model for variables with different sampling intervals

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to find a linear model to correlate data from one type of sensor (B) to a more accurate type of sensor (D). In my dataset, I have readings from three sensors - two of type B (B1 and B2) and one of type D and I want a general relation like

```
lm(D ~ B_Combined, data = dat)
```

where `B_Combined` is the combined data from B1 and B2 (`type 1` and `type 2`, below. Data from D is `type 3`).

```
               tme  degc     rh   pres           pm1         pm2.5          pm10 type
2017-10-01 21:00:00 25.97 25.908 100934    1.03726000    1.09096000    1.09125000    1
2017-10-01 21:00:59 25.97 25.908 100934    1.05086000    1.09915000    1.09943000    1
2017-10-01 21:02:00 25.91 25.929 100831    2.36670000    2.45066000    2.45077000    1
2017-10-01 21:02:59 25.91 25.929 100831  445.29000000  858.76800000  929.70800000    1
2017-10-01 21:04:00 25.66 26.104 100834 1141.44000000 2290.21000000 2544.23000000    1
2017-10-01 21:04:59 25.66 26.104 100834 1135.99000000 2285.36000000 2563.63000000    1
2017-10-01 21:00:00 26.31 26.204 100923    0.00465613    0.00478904    0.00478912    2
2017-10-01 21:00:59 25.92 26.486 100865    0.01192170    0.01266030    0.01266210    2
2017-10-01 21:02:00 25.92 26.486 100865    0.00874925    0.01089970    0.01100410    2
2017-10-01 21:02:59 25.73 26.618 100820  167.91700000  336.47300000  365.36600000    2
2017-10-01 21:03:58 25.73 26.618 100820  443.39100000  924.33600000 1027.06000000    2
2017-10-01 21:04:00 25.94 26.549 101070  459.18800000  988.95300000 1117.37000000    2
2017-10-01 21:00:29    NA     NA     NA            NA    4.00000000            NA    3
2017-10-01 21:00:59    NA     NA     NA            NA    4.00000000            NA    3
2017-10-01 21:01:29    NA     NA     NA            NA    4.00000000            NA    3
2017-10-01 21:01:59    NA     NA     NA            NA    4.00000000            NA    3
2017-10-01 21:02:29    NA     NA     NA            NA    4.00000000            NA    3
2017-10-01 21:02:59    NA     NA     NA            NA 1150.00000000            NA    3
```

The problem is that while all data was gathered during the same time period (9:00 pm to 4:00 am), sensor B records a value every second and D can record a value every [.5, 0.75] seconds (closed range).

Since all readings are at different time instants, how can I create a linear model for this data? I've tried to take the mean value for each minute for each sensor but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this?

EDIT: I'm concerned with pm2.5 only

Comment: I don't actually see a question here. What are you asking?

Comment: What can I do to create a linear model considering the readings are not all at the same time instant?

Comment: But you only have one column (`pm2.5`) that has reading for type D. Is this the only column you are trying to regress D on B?

Comment: @MrFlick The question is about both, the modeling approach and the R sytnax to be used for it. I'm only looking at pm2.5 data.

Comment: Well, first decide what model you want to use. Then come back here if you don't know how to do it in R.

Comment: You could interpolate between measurements, but if PM25 levels can undergo large, and perhaps even non-monotonic, changes between measurements, which seems to be the case for your data sample, interpolation might not be particularly representative of actual PM2.5 levels between measurements.